# Override default property value in Doctrine2 Mapped Superclass

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

The idea is that extending my `Employee` class and setting my `isManager` property would store it as true in the database whenever a DepartmentHead entity was created. This isn't working. Does anyone know why DepartmentHead entities are being stored with `isManager` equal to false?

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"employee" = "Employee", "dphead" = "DepartmentHead"})
 */
class Employee
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected static $isManager = false;

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function isManager(): bool
    {
        return static::$isManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $isManager
     */
    public static function setIsManager(bool $isManager): void
    {
        static::$isManager = $isManager;
    }
}

/** 
 * @Entity()
 */
class DepartmentHead extends Employee 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    protected static $isManager = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use static properties, Doctrine cannot cope with them properly.

With a common property, everything works as expected.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
protected $isManager = true;
```

Comment: This was the first thing I attempted.

Comment: ...and? If it solves your problem, consider marking this answer as accepted so that the question displays as answered. Update the question if it doesn't.

Comment: If that was a solution to the problem, and it being the first thing I attempted, I wouldn't have asked the question ;) I do very much appreciate your suggestion though!

Comment: I tried that without the static property and it worked. If yours doesn't, update the question so that others are not thrown off by the static and search for the problem elsewhere.